# Best practice in node-red to have an endless flow?

Tags: node.js, node-red

I want to run an endless flow in node-red but don't want to connect the end to the start, or at least want to know if there is a better way of doing this? Like e.g. a node which tells node red to start over or something?

The flow could look like a blank inject which starts once and then having some node which waits for a condition, if this condition happens the flow does something and finishes. But when it finishes, it should start to wait for the condition again.

Hope I explained it understandable :).

Thanks!

Comment: Hi Thilo, to answer properly, it would be helpful if you could define what the 'condition' is that triggers your flow. It doesn't sound like a flow sat in a loop, rather a flow that is listening for an event which it then processes. Why do you need it to be in a loop?

Comment: guess my flow reads some config data from a sqlite DB and within this config data, there is a filename set which should be waited for change. If this file changed, there should be written something back to the sqlite DB.
After the db was written, the flow should start over. 
The filename to watch for can be changed so I need to read it from the DB before waiting for the change.

Comment: Instead of circling forever (which means busy waiting), it's probably much better to use a timer node to start your flow in regular interval. See this question of mine https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44109445/node-red-how-to-make-inject-fire-at-given-seconds-per-minute to find a node that can start your flow more often than once per second.

Answer (score 0):

You mean you want the same message to keep going round and round the flow for ever?

If the content of the message can be encapsulated in the payload part of the msg object then you could have a MQTT input node on the start and a publish node at the end and so the object gets published then re-injected at the start. You would probably want to make sure there was a suitable delay node somewhere in the flow as well.

You would kick this off with a inject node that publishes a msg to the same topic when the flow is kicked off.

The other option is to keep all the state in the global context using a function block and just have a inject node at the start that fires at what ever interval you want things to flow "round" the flow.

Both of these are pretty hacky and I think you need to be a clear as to why you want a "never ending flow"